# How to allow specific ip address to access my webapp deployed in azure?

Tags: azure, web, web-applications, deployment

I have a deployed web app in azure but I want to allow only specific ip address ( or mac address if possible) to access the sites on the web app I deployed on azure. I've been searching for internet for step by step instructions but I really cannot find one. I saw several codes to paste to web.config but I do not know how to do it nor find that file.

What I understand is that I need to setup a network security group found under the settings on my web app but I cannot find it there. I can only see networking. Can someone please provide step by step instructions. TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we should create an app service Environment(virtual network), in this way, we can add **NSG** to the virtual network, then we can set **inbound rules** for this virtual network, in this way, we can control inbound traffic to web app.

We can follow this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic) to create app service environment and add NSG to web app.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.